# Tweepy streaming module language filter not working

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am trying the following code to extract tweets in french but it returns tweets in english and some other languages. Is there a syntax error ?

```
import sys
import tweepy
import config as config

consumer_key= config.CONSUMER_KEY
consumer_secret= config.CONSUMER_SECRET
access_key = config.OAUTH_TOKEN
access_secret = config.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)



class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.lang
            #, status.user.location, status.user.description

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=["rame", "lent", "long", "beug", "beugg", "beugge", "bug"], languages = ["fr"])
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues right now. I created an issue on the Tweepy Github.https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/567

Comment: thanks this is quite bizzare that the language filter is not working

Comment: Can it just be that there were not tweets happening during that time with those criteria? I'm doing a very similar thing right now and just by filtering on the sample stream on French produces just about 40 tweets per minute. Have you tried removing or reducing the filter track list and see whether that changes anything?

Answer (score 1):

a bit of an old post but I've been experiencing the same problem lately : the keyword search does not seem to work properly, it seems to return tweets even if they don't have the keyword. The solution which worked for me was to use twython and the API v2...

Answer (score 0):

Try language instead of language**s**.

Comment: Having similar issues. `filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'`